# Firebase and Swift username case-sensitive

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When registering a new user, and when I look in the Firebase user database, if the user exists he does not create the accunt, otherwise the registration is completed. But if there is a user named "Tony" in the database and I try to register with the username "tony", Firebase don't understand that "Tony" and "tony" are the same username. I want to solve this.

I state that I wrote the code in swift.

Comment: Always allow lowercase letters in the app side while registering! Its the usual way of identifying usernames.
So whenever a username with the same name comes up, firebase recognise it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fastest way with querying is to do this:

1. Duplicate your username list in a new list where all your usernames are lowercased
2. Lowercase the new username
3. Check if that username exist in your duplicated list (where all usernames are lowercased)
4. When it does not exists, append the real username without lowercase to the list with the usernames where they are case-sensitive and to the lowercased username list.

This duplicates data, but it is not that bad since it are only usernames.

Comment: @rizzoantonio There's probably no reason to create another list of usernames; just store a lowercase version of the username in the user node and use that to query for a match. Of course usernames are often only stored as lower case (think; email address) so that may be the ultimate solution.